# Determine if the members of a set can be made to equal a given number

Tags: logic, arithmetic

Is there an easy way to determine if some combination of addition, subtraction, multiplication, and division will enable the numbers in a set to equal a given number?

For example, if I have the numbers $[6, 6, 4, 3, 1]$ and I want to determine if the number $41$ can be arrived at by operations performed on them how would I go about determining that.  (This case can be solved by $((6 + 6) \cdot {3}) + 4 + 1 = 41$, I'm looking for a general way to solve this problem for a program I'm writing).

Comment: I myself, do not know of any formula, but this article speaks of methods and ideas. Have you ever seen the UK show 'Countdown'?http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1607

Comment: I suspect this is easy in the sense of "you can write a program to brute force it" but hard in the sense of "there's no better algorithm than brute force". Someone with more free time than me could probably run a reduction with [subset sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is known to be NP-hard

Comment: Oh, wow. I just noticed this is extremely old. Sorry this probably isn't relevant anymore